# Is it possible to make iChat read out loud conversations as they happen?

Tags: macos, ichat, text-to-speech

Lately I've been using iChat for some time and sometimes it's boring to switch windows to read the next text. Snow Leopard (and other Mac OS X versions) has a text to speech feature, but I see it only works for selected text and pressing a combo key.

Is it possible to somehow hack iChat to read out loud automatically the incoming text from a chat window? Bonus points if you can make different people use different voices (one being a chipmunk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the iChat preferences under the Alerts panel you can select the event `Message Received`, then check the box underneath that says `Run an AppleScript script:` and use AppleScript to change the voice depending on user and speak the message.

```
using terms from application "iChat"
   on message received theText from theBuddy for theChat
      if (theBuddy = "Joe") then
         set theVoice to "Bubbles"
      else 
         set theVoice to "Bruce"
      end if
      say theText using theVoice
   end message received
end using terms from
```

Unfortunately, there is no chipmunk voice included with osx.

**Edit:**

Fortunately, there's a way to emulate the chipmunk voice. :)

```
if (theBuddy = "Joe the Chipmunk") then
   say theText using "Bruce" pitch 75 speaking rate 250
else 
   say theText using "Bruce"
end if
```

Comment: Help!  When I try this, I get this message whenever it runs the script:  Event: Message Received in Chat Room
File: speak.applescript
Error: Error -1708